# return all substrings from a list of strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I need to search a df column and return all substrings from a list.

```
myList= ['a cat', 'the dog', 'a cow']

example df
'col A'
there was a cat with the dog
the cow was brown
the dog was sick
```

this splits the words in the list and only returns single words

```
df['col B'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([word for word in x.split() if word in (myList)]))
```

also tried to add in an np any...

```
df['col B'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(np.any(word for word in df['col A'] if word in (myList))))
```

need to return

```
'col B'
a cat;the dog
NaN
the dog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, you were close:

```
import numpy as np

df['col B'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([m for m in myList if m in x])).replace('',np.nan)
```

result:

```
                          col A          col B
0  there was a cat with the dog  a cat;the dog
1             the cow was brown            NaN
2              the dog was sick        the dog
```

Answer (score 1):

You may

```
s = df.col.str.extractall(f'({"|".join(myList)})')
res = s.groupby(s.index.get_level_values(0))[0].agg(';'.join)
df.loc[res.index, 'new'] = res
```

---

```
                            col            new
0  there was a cat with the dog  a cat;the dog
1             the cow was brown            NaN
2              the dog was sick        the dog
```