# How to replace values in a pandas dataframe with the ones on a list by searching for similar values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I have a dataframe with data from cars, particularly, the column car-name has the full name including brand and model, small snippet of the list:

```
['Toyota Yaris HB s', 'Bmw Serie 3 340 M xDrive', 'Nissan Versa Platinum', 'Alfa Romeo Mito Hatch Back Mito Veloce', 'Mitsubishi Outlander SE', 'Nissan Kicks Fan Edition', 'Dodge Vision 1.6l, Infiniti Q50 Sport', 'Chevrolet Aveo LS (Línea nueva)', 'Gmc Acadia All Terrain', 'Volkswagen T-Cross Trendline', 'Mazda Cx-3 i Sport', 'Chevrolet Camaro LT', 'Dodge Durango R/T', 'Chevrolet Spark HB LT', 'Dodge Journey GT', 'Suzuki Grand Vitara GLS', 'Mini Countryman S Countryman Sport']
```

I need to get the brand/maker on a different column so I managed to separate the first word from the column using this code I found on another question:

```
df['make'] = df['car-name'].str.split().str.get(0)
```

From there I get this unique values:

```
['Acura', 'Alfa', 'Audi', 'Baic', 'Bmw', 'Buick', 'Cadillac', 'Chevrolet', 'Chrysler', 'Dodge', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Gmc', 'Honda', 'Hyundai', 'Infiniti', 'Jac',
 'Jaguar', 'Jeep', 'Kia', 'Land', 'Lincoln', 'Maserati', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mg', 'Mini', 'Mitsubishi', 'Nissan', 'Peugeot', 'Porsche', 'Renault', 'Seat', 'Smart',
 'Subaru', 'Suzuki', 'Tesla', 'Toyota', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo']
```

This would be enough for most cases but other values like 'Alfa', 'Baic', 'Gmc', 'Mercedes'. I'd like to normalize them to 'Alfa Romeo', 'BAIC', 'GMC', 'Mercedes-Benz' respectively by looking for corresponding matches on a comprehensive list of car makers that have the correct casing full names.

My logic:

```
#Getting the unique values from the whole list 
brands = np.sort(df['make'].unique())
#Loop for searching those unique values on the car maker catalog and replace the search term with the match on the list on the 
for brand in brands:
     df['make'].replace(brand value i.e: 'Alfa', "result from searching brand on list" in this case: 'Alfa Romeo')
```

Comment: from my understanding, your idea is (#1 to split the car name to `brand_name` in the df) , (#2 to search and match `brand_name` with `car_brands`) am I right?

Comment: Hi Amzar! Yes. You are correct. #1 is done but I'm struggling with #2.

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? [mre] [ask] [Help] PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your post. [edit] PS "minimal" includes (representative) data. All your actual cases <> minimal.

Comment: Sorry for my poor format in writing. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

USE `df['brands'] = df['car-name'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([m for m in lst if m in x])).replace('',np.nan)`
I am making `lst` from `df['make']` column so the small caps and large caps issue will not occur.

Also if any car brand contain two words for ex- `Alfa Romeo`, then use `df['brands'] = np.select([df['brands'].str.contains('Alfa')], [df['brands']+ 'Romeo'], df['brands'])` condition to solve this issue.Adding 2nd word explicitly.

Updated Code-

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = ['Toyota Yaris HB s', 'BMW Serie 3 340 M xDrive','Baic','Bmw', 'GMC World','BAIC Green','Alfa Romeo Mito Hatch Back Mito Veloce','Mercedes-Benz A3212 Model']
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['car-name'])
df['make'] = df['car-name'].str.split().str.get(0)
#Making lst from dataframe column df['make']
lst = df['make'].tolist()#Create list of brands
df['brands'] = df['car-name'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([m for m in lst if m in x])).replace('',np.nan)
#Special condition if df['brand'] contains two words
df['brands'] = np.select([df['brands'].str.contains('Alfa')], [df['brands']+ 'Romeo'], df['brands'])

# print dataframe.
df
```

Output-

```
      car-name                   make   brands
0   Toyota Yaris HB s            Toyota Toyota
1   BMW Serie 3 340 M xDrive       BMW  BMW
2   Baic                           Baic Baic
3   Bmw                            Bmw  Bmw
4   GMC World                      GMC  GMC
5   BAIC Green                     BAIC BAIC
6   Alfa Romeo Mito Hatch          Alfa AlfaRomeo
7   Mercedes-Benz A3212 Mode  Mercedes-Benz Mercedes-Benz
```

ref links- [return all substrings from a list of strings in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948850/return-all-substrings-from-a-list-of-strings-in-a-dataframe-column)

[return all substrings in a string in a new column (from a list of substrings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316951/return-all-substrings-in-a-string-in-a-new-column-from-a-list-of-substrings)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure how your function works at all but I replicated it and didn't get the same results as you did. I think it was mainly because your data already has the right names from the start like 'BAIC' in my data is 'Baic'. From the df['brands'].unique() I got values like 'Jetta;Volkswagen', 'Cupra;Seat', 'DS;Volkswagen' among others. ATM was trying a for with all the unique values in df['make'] with this: res = [string for string in MARCAS if marca in string] and got nice results except for when a name in catalog is in full caps vs capitalized value in the data.

Comment: Correct, `lst` will not compare 'BAIC' & 'Baic' as one in small and other in full caps.

Store words in `lst` same as in `df['make]`, so that above code will compare and update `brands` column accordingly.

Comment: But by doing so  wouldn't I be able to normalize the two letter brands like Alfa Romeo, but end up with the same capitalized 'Baic', 'Bmw', 'Gmc'. Instead of the correct full caps values?

Comment: This are the first values I get from the funtion I commented: ['Acura']
['Alfa Romeo']
['Audi']
[]
[]
['Buick']
['Cadillac']. I get blanks from 'BAIC' and 'BMW' (among others) because the names in the data are capitalized while the ones in the list are correctly written in full caps so the search returns no results.

Comment: you can keep the elements is lst with same caps with df'make' then Nan values will not be present. Code is updated, hope this will solve all issues.