# return all substrings in a string in a new column (from a list of substrings)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have a column of product names and I want to extract brand names for the same from my list.

`my_list=['Lakme','Olay','Estee Lauder']`

The column `df['product_name']` has product names like `'Lakme Absolute Blur Perfect Makeup Primer'`.

I want to create a new column `df['brand']` if the brand name lies in the string from `my_list`.

I tried

```
df['brand']=df['product_name'].apply(lambda x: True if any(s in x for s in my_list) else False)
```

This just gives True/False. How do I extract brand in one step?

Comment: I found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948850/return-all-substrings-from-a-list-of-strings-in-a-dataframe-column This works

Comment: Is `my_list` long? If not, you could do `df['brand'] = df['product_name'].where(df['product_name'].str.contains('|'.join(my_list)))`.